# $h(e^{i\theta}) $ imaginary implies $h(z)$ imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $h$ is a holomorphic function on the open disk $B={|z|<1+\epsilon}$ where $\epsilon >0$.

Suppose that $h(e^{i\theta}) $ is purely imaginary for every real number $\theta$.

I want to prove that $h(z)$ is purely imaginary for every $z\in B$.

At first I thought the statement as false since there are many mobius transformations which send the unit circle onto the imaginary axis, but someone pointed out that those mobius transformations are not holomorphic since the may have poles. Now I'm thinking maybe the function is constant and I would need to use the open map theorm , so basicly I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Write $h= u+iv.$ Then $u,$ which is harmonic on $D(0,1+\epsilon),$ equals $0$ on the unit circle. Apply the maximum principle for harmonic functions to $u.$